# Javascript, trying to add linebreak inside create text node method

Tags: javascript

This is my script:

```
<script>
/*jslint browser:true */
var i;
var out = document.getElementById("output");
var args = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", 1, 2, 4 + 4];
function displayArgs() {
    "use strict";
    for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        out.appendChild(document.createTextNode(args[i] + "<br>"));
    }
}

displayArgs(args);
</script>
```

my output so far all appears on a single line with the break tags showing rather than b

Answer (score 20):

`document.createTextNode` prevents text from being rendered as html.
Try this instead.

```
/*jslint browser:true */
var i;
var out = document.getElementById("output");
var args = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", 1, 2, 4 + 4];
function displayArgs() {
    "use strict";
    for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        out.appendChild(document.createTextNode(args[i]));
        out.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
displayArgs(args);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LVm9z/

Comment: @user1769839 Click on the arrow under the number on the top left side of the answer you wish to select as correct. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Just wanted to add a note for anyone out there who might be using jquery: `appendChild` is not supported so you would have to do `$("#someElement").append(document.create...)`. This tripped me up for a bit this morning :)

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a text node, so html tags are ignored. Use document.createElement instead:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.id = 'myDiv';
myDiv.innerHTML = 'blah!<br/>';
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

Comment: wouldn't that require me to make a separate element for each item in the loop?

Comment: You already ARE creating a separate element for each item in the loop with your document.createTextNode(...) call.

Answer (score 3):

A text node is a text node, if it contains a `<br>` (or *any* HTML), it won't be parsed as HTML, as a text node's data is only treated as text.

You could add...

```
out.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```