# How to line break in a return value? Or a better way of returning HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a line break in my showPhoto() function but nothing seems to work. I've tried using br, tried using html() but still didn't budge. The comment in my Javascript code shows the return line i am talking about. 
If there any better methods to achieve my desired result??

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

JS :

```
    function photo(theCountry, theLocation, theCamera, theDescription) {
    this.photoCountry = theCountry;
    this.photoLocation = theLocation;
    this.photoCamera = theCamera;
    this.photoDescription = theDescription;

    this.showPhoto = function() {
    // How do i create line breaks here?? I want each sub heading on a different line.
    return 'Country: ' + this.photoCountry + ' Location: ' + this.photoLocation + ' Shot With: ' + this.photoCamera + ' Description: ' + this.photoDescription;    
    }

}

var photo1 = new photo('New Zealand', 'Queenstown', 'Canon 550D', '...');

var photo2 = new photo('Singapore', 'Skyline', 'Canon 550D', '....');

var photo3 = new photo('Canada', 'Vancouver', 'Canon 550D', '...');

var photo4 = new photo('New Zealand', 'Lake Wanaka', 'Canon 550D', '....');

var photo5 = new photo('Australia', 'Mornington Peninsula', 'Canon 550D', '...')

$('.photoImg').click(function() {
    var sourceImage = document.createElement('img');
        sourceImage.className = 'photoFocus';
        sourceImage.src = this.src;
    var theDiv = document.getElementById('selectionContainer');
        $(theDiv).html(sourceImage);
    var textDiv = document.createElement('div');
    textDiv.setAttribute('id', 'textContainer');
    var textNodeArray = {'photo1': photo1, 'photo2': photo2, 'photo3': photo3, 'photo4': photo4, 'photo5': photo5}
    $('#textContainer').html(document.createTextNode(textNodeArray[this.id].showPhoto()));          

});
```

Comment: You are not writing text. You are writing html. Use the correct html element and css to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really add a line break inside a TextNode (created by createTextNode).

See this :

[Javascript, trying to add linebreak inside create text node method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041388/javascript-trying-to-add-linebreak-inside-create-text-node-method)

A solution could be to have your `showPhoto` function return a list of the text for the different lines, and create several TextNodes, separated by "br" nodes.

Something in the spirit of :

```
this.showPhoto = function() {
  // How do i create line breaks here?? I want each sub heading on a different line.

  return ["Country : " + this.photoCountry,
        "Location : " + this.photoLocation, ...]
}
```

Then (probably using an iterator on lines, any maybe wraping DOM elements to please jquery)

```
var lines = textNodeArray[this.id].showPhoto())

$('#textContainer').append(document.createTextNode(lines[0]);
$('#textContainer').append(document.createElement("br"));
$('#textContainer').append(document.createTextNode(lines[1]);
..
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can Use CSS like**

```
li{
float:left;
padding:5px; /* or anything you need */
margin-top:10px;  /* or anything you need */
}
```

**This your HTML**

```
  <ul> 
        <li> <img src='images/newzealand.jpg' class='photoImg' id='photo1'> </li>
        <li> <img src='images/singapore.jpg' class='photoImg' id='photo2'> </li>
        <li> <img src='images/vancouver.jpg' class='photoImg' id='photo3'> </li>
        <li> <img src='images/newzealand2.jpg' class='photoImg' id='photo4'> </li>
        <li> <img src='images/mornington.jpg' class='photoImg' id='photo5'> </li>
        <li> <img src='images/newzealand1.jpg' class='photoImg' id='photo6'> </li>
        <li> <img src='images/newzealand3.jpg' class='photoImg' id='photo7'> </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `<br>` tag in your output (which you will treat as an HTML fragment):

```
return 'Country: ' + this.photoCountry + '<br>Location: ' + this.photoLocation + '<br>Shot With: ' + this.photoCamera + '<br>Description: ' + this.photoDescription;
```

As you're using jQuery, you can directly output the the HTML returned by your `showPhoto` method:

```
$('#textContainer').html(textNodeArray[this.id].showPhoto());
```

jQUery will parse the HTML string and take care of the actual DOM node creation for you.