# How to allow line breaks when creating text nodes via Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wish to allow a user to enter a Message of the Day, but I need to account for the potential for malicious content.

My view is as follows:

```
<div id="dvMOTD">
    <div>
        <span id="dvActualMOTD"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I didn't create this view, so I'm not sure why it's nested as it is).

To do this, I was originally just doing the following:

```
$("#dvActualMOTD").append(document.createTextNode(someStr));
```

This worked, until I realized I can't use line breaks. I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13041452/1189566) which seemed to work, so I adapted it to my solution like so:

```
function MotdLoad(str)
{
    try
    {
        var arr = str.split("&lt;BR&gt;");

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == "")
                $("#dvActualMOTD").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            else
                $("#dvActualMOTD").append(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
        }
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        logError(err, arguments.callee.trace());
    }
}
```

This threw the following exception:

> TypeError - Java Script Error : $(...).appendChild is not a function

So I thought it was an issue with the `span` element. I tried using `dvMOTD` instead, but I get the same exception.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673905/appendchild-is-not-a-function-javascript) but here the user is trying to create the parent elements through the Javascript itself, whereas mine exist in the view's HTML itself.

So, how can I create a line break when handling user input without allowing the full range of HTML?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have an `appendChild` method: https://api.jquery.com/?s=appendChild . Why don't you use `.append` just like in the `else` clause?

Comment: Ah, brilliant. That fixed my problem entirely; if you want to submit it as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thank you! Such a simple fix :)

Comment: IMO this question should be closed as a typo.